# Why Do I get rendering issues in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-developer-api

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.yossikally.hello.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
        <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I built the simplest hello world project.
In the xml design pane I get what's in the picture[image]

Tried to change themes and change version.  Get the same

Comment: please show your xml file

Comment: the one where you have CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add to your App gradle file [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
```

Comment: Accepted but not entirely full. original 23.2.0 is n good. has to be changed back to 23.1.1, also only them that works is "NoActionBar", any other theme - e.g. Holo will give a full page of warning as for renderizaton issues.